# SKD19 vs SDK24 - Usage of API documented as @since 1.8+

Tags: android, sdk

In my app there is an error.
[image]

Error says - "Usage of API documented as @since 1.8+..".

App is running fine on sdk 24, but when I run it on minSDK - 19, then it just crashes on that error line, where PriorityQueue in initialized. I checked that class PriorityQueue - added on API level 1. Then where is the problem?

**Q: How to fix it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [PriorityQueue (Comparator comparator)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue(java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20E%3E)) was added in API 24 so it is not backward compatible with older version (minsdk should be 24)
can use any other version of constructor mentioned under the [summary](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) except this one.

Although the closest one to your current use is the one with initial capacity

[PriorityQueue (int initialCapacity, 
                Comparator comparator)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue(int,%20java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20E%3E))

Other solution is
You can put a check against the current API like

```
PriorityQueue<Cell> pq;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Nougat) {
      pq = new  PriorityQueue(new CellComparator());
}else{
      pq = new  PriorityQueue(50/*initial capacity*/,new CellComparator());
}
```

where `initial capacity` mean : PQ internally use array with default capacity as `11` so in case you have an idea about number of elements in advance then it better to define the initial capacity of queue array because it can prevent recreation of larger array and copying of array element at run time

Comment: what is that initial capacity?

Comment: @TomTom initial capacity mean , the number of element it can hold , it is basically use to save memory , when you have the idea in advance about the number of elements you need to store although its capacity grows automatically when needed

Comment: @TomTom i am glad that i could help , happy coding

Answer (score 2):

the problem is not with `PriorityQueue` but with the constructor, you are using. As per the documentation on [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue(java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20E%3E))

[image]

This constructor with the comparator is added in API 24 and hence not available with lower API levels.

you can try the below one [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue(int,%20java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20E%3E))

```
PriorityQueue(int initialCapacity, Comparator<? super E> comparator)
//Creates a PriorityQueue with the specified initial capacity that orders its elements according to the specified comparator.
```